# New line for CSV results

Tags: python, csv

I got this code from [Time data '\n' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61848097/time-data-n-does-not-match-format-m-d-y-python) and it works, but I was wondering if I can get the output in new line.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    dates = [row[6] for row in reader]

dates.sort(key=lambda ts: datetime.strptime(ts, "%m/%d/%Y"))

print(dates)
```

Currently, the output is as follows:

```
['2/15/1956', '8/7/1966', '3/10/1988', '7/15/1988', '9/11/1991']
```

Would like to have it as, if possible:

```
2/15/1956
8/7/1966
3/10/1988
7/15/1988 
9/11/1991
```

I tried to sort it out by using this code, but it would generate an error:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime


with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
      dates = (row[6])
      dates.sort(key=lambda ts: datetime.strptime(ts, "%m/%d/%Y"))

      print(dates)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\Desktop\sample.py", line 9, in <module>
    dates.sort(key=lambda ts: datetime.strptime(ts, "%m/%d/%Y"))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: In your second example dates is actually one date string at a time, so sorting it makes no sense. If you want to print each date on a new line, why not just iterate over the list you already have in your first example, rather than printing the whole list?

Comment: Because that list is only a part of the original record (which has over 501 records). Reiterating it over the list will be time-consuming, if not impossible. :)

The main goal is to sort the whole list base on their age.

Comment: "over 501" is ~zero to a computer. If you can sort them (`O(n log n)`) in sensible time, you can certainly iterate over them (`O(n)`). What makes you think it would be impossible to output all of the dates and, if so, how do you think you could get your desired output of all of the dates?